# Sparx EA - How to capture event (e.g. status change)

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is there an automated way to detect when a requirement's status is set to 'Approved'? The business need is to alert an external app each time a requirement is approved.

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I cannot see anything in the Sparx Help that offers a clue. That's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: At Stack Overflow, questions are not just for the person asking them, but are intended to be foundo by others facing the same problem. Therefore, a good question shows that the person asking it has put some effort into finding the answer on their own, and where exactly they've got stuck. "How do I do X, please help" is not a good question. Please read through the pages in the help center, and especially https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Voting to close as per previous comment.

Comment: Look into the help: EA_OnContextItemChanged

Comment: I don't agree completely with @Uffe, although a little bit more effort couldn't have hurt. But it is indeed hard to figure out something like that when you don't have a clue where to start looking. Therefore I answered the question anyway.

Comment: It's not a question of agreeing with me, but of adhering to the Stack Overflow ethos. If we don't all consciously keep the quality of questions up (which includes getting rid of bad questions and explaining to new members how they should be asking questions instead), the site will deteriorate to a point where it is no longer useful to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to to build an add-in for Enterprise Architect. I wrote some [articles about that subject](http://bellekens.com/writing-ea-add-ins/) that should help you get started.

In this add-in you can implement the "events" `EA_ConContextItemChanged` to capture the status before it was changed and `EA_OnNotifyContextItemModified` to compare it with the previously captured status.

It might be possible that you can also use [workflow scripts](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/the_model_repository/workflow_scripts.html), but I'm not sure (nobody really uses that).